# Even position should have fibonacci, odd position should have prime numbers in java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nthterm {

    int k;

    public int fibonacci(int n) {
        int a = 0, b = 1, c;

        if (n == 0) {
            return b;
        }


        for (int i = 0; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            c = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = c;
        }

        return b;
    }

    public int prime(int n) {
        int result = 0;
        boolean isprime = true;
        for (int j = 2; j < n; j++) {
            if (n % j == 0) {
                isprime = false;
            }

        }
        if (isprime) {
            result = n;
        }

        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENTER:");
        int k = sc.nextInt();
        Nthterm fib = new Nthterm();

        int[] arr1 = new int[k + 1];

        for (int n = 0; n <= k; n++) {

            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                arr1[n] = fib.fibonacci(n);
            } else {
                arr1[n] = fib.prime(n);

            }

        }
        for (int element: arr1) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

I have written a code if n is even it will call Fibonacci, if n is odd it will prime function and store it in an  array.

But Prime function is giving error at 9th position.

Output :

> ENTER: 10 1 1 2 3 3 5 5 7 8 0 13

How can we write prime function to fill the odd position?

Answer (score 0):

Your `prime(int n)` method should return the n'th prime number. Instead it returns `n` if `n` is prime and `0` if `n` is not prime. Therefore it returns `0` when you pass `9` to it, since `9` is not prime.

It seems that in each consecutive call to `prime()` you want to get the next prime number. Therefore, you can change `prime()` to return the next prime number larger than `n`:

```
public int nextPrime(int n0) {
    int n = n0 + 1;
    boolean isPrime = false;
    while (!isPrime) {
        isPrime = true;
        for(int j = 2; j < n;j++) {
            if (n % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                n++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Now, instead of calling:

```
arr1[n]=fib.prime(n)
```

You should call:

```
arr1[n]= n < 2 ? fib.nextPrime(0) : fib.nextPrime(arr1[n-2]);
```